# Bash command executed in Java if cuttoff

Tags: java, bash, command-line, command

I would like to execute a bash script I have written, however it seems to be cutting off during execution.

The script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
pico2wave -w=tmp/temp.wav "$1"
aplay tmp/temp.wav
rm tmp/temp.wav
```

and the Java code is:

```
String command = "bash vox '" + text + "'";
System.out.println(command);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

If variable `text` = "Hello World", the program prints:

```
 bash vox 'Hello World'
```

However the bash script seems to only execute for the first word in the command.

When I execute the command in a terminal, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt to use single quotes fails. Actually, Java already splits the string at whitespaces (or rather, [using a StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29)), not the shell, so the quote doesn't work. Instead, try using

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "bash", "vox", text });
```

or better yet, use a `ProcessBuilder`.

Comment: Wierdly, my IDE is telling me: unclosed character literal,
unclosed character literal,
not a statement,
unclosed character literal,
unclosed character literal,
not a statement,
';' expected,
not a statement.

Comment: Thanks - there was a missing/wrong quote in my code, and it was not an array as it should have been... always compile things before posting, sorry. Thanks to @that other guy.

Comment: I've gotten it to work by passing the arguments as a String array. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use the process builder. Here is an example:

```java
  ArrayList<String> listCommands = new ArrayList<String>();
  // Optional for opening a new command window, useful for the output of the tool you started, uncomment to use
  // the problem with this is that "waitFor()" (see below) will return immediatialy without waiting for the tool you started
  //listCommands.add("cmd");
  //listCommands.add("/c");
  // listCommands.add("start");

  listCommands.add(bash);
  listCommands.add(vox);
  // path
  String text = <your text>
  if (text .contains(" ")) {
       text = "\"" + text + "\"";
  }
  listCommands.add(text );

  // add more parameters if you need them here

  String[] cmd = new String[listCommands.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < listCommands.size(); i++) {
       cmd[i] = listCommands.get(i);
  }
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
  //  optional execution directory, uncomment to use
  // pb.directory(new java.io.File(pathOut));
  Process p = pb.start();
  try {
      // waits till the process is finished, delete if you don't need it
        p.waitFor();
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       // here your code 
  }
```

Comment: you mix up text and sout names but the right way of doing things

Comment: thx, this has been my own code and I forgot some stuff to replace